# funciones recursivas

Tags: python

Esto es lo que he avanzado:

```
def sumatoria(n,p):
    if n < 1:
        return 0
    else:
        return n + sumatoria(n-1,p) + n
print(sumatoria(5,2))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

El código está casi bien.

```
def sumatoria(n, p):
    if n < 1:
        return 0
    else:
        return p * n + sumatoria(n-1, p)
```

Lo primero es la condición de término, que depende de `n` (la parte variable), no de `p`, la parte fija:

```
if n < 1:
```

Después, la expresión correcta es:

```
p * n + sumatoria(n-1, p)
```

pues vas recorriendo del último `n` hacia `n = 1`. En cada paso multiplicas `p` por `n` y le agregas la sumatoria desde `n-1`.

Comment: Muchas gracias.